# "Shortcut" arrows in fonts

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I notice there are shortcut-like arrows in a few of my fonts.

Anybody knows what these means?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those arrows indicate fonts that are stored in a location other than `C:\Windows\Fonts`. When you attempt to open that folder in Windows Explorer, it actually opens a special fonts utility with all installed fonts on the system. To get an actual listing of the files in the directory, use `dir C:\Windows\Fonts` in the command prompt.

Installed fonts are actually listed in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` registry key; the value name is the font name and the data is the location. If the location has no path specified, the default fonts folder is assumed (`%SystemRoot%\Fonts`). If there is a path specified, then you get that shortcut arrow when you attempt to use the Windows fonts utility.

[[image: Screenshot of registry key]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbqfA.png)

You can also see the path of a specific font in the properties:

[[image: Screenshot of properties window]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96IVn.png)

[[image: Screenshot of properties window]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiSra.png)

Comment: I've only somehow just come across this in the past few weeks.  Fonts that are used by other applications, even if they aren't "installed" via the click-menu, can end up as shortcuts here.  This can be fun when it comes time to update or remove fonts that an application installed.